# Show folder in Gallery instantly

Tags: android, gallery

I created an app that saves images to a folder on the SD card. I noticed it isn't show instantly in the Gallery app, after some time it shows up but when my first image is saved I can't find the folder. Is there a way to add the folder to the Gallery as soon as the first image is saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to inform the Media Scanner to add the new image to the database using the `MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` intent. This can be achieved using the following code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;

sendBroadcast (
    new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, 
                Uri.parse( "file://" + "path-to-file" ) )
);
```

In the above code replace the `"path-to-file"` string with the actual path to the new image.

You can also use the `ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED` intent to scan the entire external storage if needed.